# Rounding off values in the Kable

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi just want to ask on how can I round off the values in my table, into just 2 decimal places. 
Here are my codes for the table output.

```
kable(Varimportance$anova, caption= "ANOVA Table")
kable(Varimportance$importance, caption= "Variable Importance")
```

And this is what my table looks like there are values that has 5, 8 or more decimal places. And I want it to be just 2 decimal places.[image]

Comment: Check argument `digits` in `kable` function.

Comment: Thanks this works. I just put digits=2 inside the kable function.

Answer (score 12):

As suggested in pogibas comment above, use the `digits` argument.  The default value is `getOption("digits")`.

```r
kable(Varimportance$anova, caption= "ANOVA Table", digits=2)
kable(Varimportance$importance, caption= "Variable Importance", digits=2)
```

Comment: How can I set a global digits=2 for all kable tables?

Comment: Note this only works if you spell `digits` properly. My code with `digis = 2` is the reason I visited this page!